# How do I stagger Xamarin Forms animation in the ChildAdded event handler?

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

I have a StackLayout that I am binding to using BindableLayout. When I click a button I add items via a for loop to the ItemSource. This works fine and fires the ChildAdded event on the StackLayout.

In the event handler I am just doing a simple FadeTo animation and that seems to work fine.

The problem I am having is I cannot seem to get the animations to stagger for each child element. All the FadeTo animations occur at the same time, so all children fade in together. I want it to work more like the built in animation in the CollecitonView but I can't seem to find where they do their animations in the XF code on github.

Can someone tell me how to do this? Maybe my approach is all wrong, not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see

Comment: Is that you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to add the items with animation one by one ? you could check the simple sample,see if it that you want to achive ：

the **StackLayout** :

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" ChildAdded="Stack_ChildAdded">

</StackLayout>
<Button Text="add" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
```

then in the **page.xaml.cs**(here when i click the button,i will add 5 Labels every 1 second):

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            Label label = new Label() { Text = "Label" };
            pickerStack.Children.Add(label);
            await Task.Delay(1000);


        }

    }

private async void Stack_ChildAdded(object sender, ElementEventArgs e)
    {

            Label label = e.Element as Label;
            label.Opacity = 0;
            await label.FadeTo(1, 1000);

    }
```

like the effect below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I eventually figured out as well. I had been trying to do the delay in the ChildAdded event and eventually figured out that doing it on the BindableLayout.ItemsSource worked. Sort of the same as what you have except I'm not adding to the Children directly I'm looping over the data elements and adding them to BindableLayout.ItemsSource. Thanks!